# Cycles from a specific node in directed graph networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, cycle, basis

I am trying to find the independent cycles coming out from from a specific node in a graph in netowrkx. The algorithms there are implemented for undirected (with an option for node) and for undirected (without an option for node selection).

Conversion from undirected to directed will not work since you lose some edges. Using multigraph will also not work since the algorithm of cycles is only implemented for undirected graphs. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have some code or pseudo-code?

Comment: "The algorithms there are implemented for undirected (with an option for node) and for undirected (without an option for node selection)." --- Which algorithms are these?